# Fiddler root certificate location

Tags: https, vagrant, fiddler

Is it possible to export the fiddler root cert so other users can use it?.

I'm wanting to distribute a vagrant/docker image for my team. We basically need to use fiddler to make SSL work (making the guest vm trust fiddlers cert and then routing everything through fiddler on the host).

I'd like to have the vagrantmachine trust fiddler by trusting a root CA we share. So the vm would trust this CA and not need to be configured everytime.

Is there a way to export fiddlers root CA (private key) and install this on another machine?.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can export Fiddler's certificate by clicking the "Export Root Certificate to Desktop" button on the tab where you enabled HTTPS (Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS).

Alternatively, you can simply visit `http://fiddlerPC:8888/` from the other clients and a link on that page offers the certificate for download.

.CER files do not contain the private key, and you do not need to distribute the private key to other machines for them to trust the certificate.

If you want to include the private key, you need to use mmc.exe with `CertMgr.msc`; right-click on the root, choose `All Tasks` > `Export...`

[image: CertManager]

Note that having multiple different Fiddler root certificates on a single PC will confuse Windows; use CertMgr.msc or Fiddler's "Remove Interception Certificates" button to remove any old roots before installing the new one.

Comment: Where is the actually root cert stored/called though? (I'm having trouble finding where the root private key is located) and how I would tell fiddler to use one that was generated previously, there appears to be zero doc on how this is done. 
That link seems like it actually might be a good alternative, the vagrant machines could go to that and download it on provisioning.

Comment: The default Fiddler certificate logic will use whatever `DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot` certificate is installed in the Personal Store on the machine in question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on happen-stance while searching.

1. Open Fiddler's Options.
2. Turn on Decrypt SSL, THEN click the Actions button on the upper-right of that tabbed area. (Exporting is not available unless you have it checked)