# HttpClient PutAsync Issues Hanging Or 404 Returned

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, put, dotnet-httpclient

Try as I might I can't get the HttpClient.PutAsync method to work correctly.  I was able to get the GetAsync method working fine.  I'm also able to make the PUT call successfully in Postman [image: postman screenshot]

This is the code I am using when I get a 404 not found.

```
 public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsJsonAsync<Contact>(HttpClient client, Contact contact)
{
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-TOKEN","MyT0k3n"); 
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);    
var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return await client.PutAsync("https://survey.qualtrics.com/API/v3/mailinglists/ML_123456/contacts/MLRP_123456", stringContent);

}
```

The Contact class has variables such as "unsubscribed".

I also tried this (https://gist.github.com/alexandrevicenzi/9216739) but when I Wait the task the thread hangs and times out:

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutJsonAsync(HttpClient client, string requestUri, Type type, object value)
{

    return client.PutAsync(requestUri, new ObjectContent(type, value, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json"));
}
```

I'm honestly not very familiar with async, await, or HttpClient. I've used HttpWebRequest and WebRequest in the past.  I attempted a PUT with my old methods and was unsuccessful. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Send both request through fiddler and show us the result. I would guess your Request is not formatted proper -> 404.

Comment: Thank you @burnsi!! This is rather embarrassing.. I should have configured fiddler for https and tried before asking here. My request URI was missing a "/". so naturally 404. I was too focused on syntax and missed the typo. I appreciate the help, your comment is right and lead me to find my problem. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time when your receive a 404 on such a task your request url is malformed.

Tip:

Try fiddler to capture both requests and compare them in raw version.

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: This answer was helpful for me configuring HTTPS in fiddler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440877/fiddler-root-certificate-location